# Operators from $\ell_\infty$

Tags: banach-spaces, operator-theory

It is well-known that non-weakly compact operators from $\ell_\infty$ into any Banach space act as isomorphisms on some subspace of $\ell_\infty$ isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$. I have a question in this spirit.

Suppose that $T\colon \ell_\infty \to c_0$ is a bounded linear operator. Then $T$ is not weakly compact. Can it happen that $T|_{c_0}\colon c_0\to c_0$ is weakly compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every bounded linear operator from $\ell_\infty$ to a separable space is weakly compact.  This follows, for example, from the fact that $\ell_\infty$ is a Grothendieck space (use Google).

Comment: May I suggest giving a reference (to either a paper or a webpage) instead of "use Google".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128388/ell-infty-a-grothendieck-space